# How to make JBoss v4.2 look for applications in directories other than default?

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

Out of the box, JBoss 4.2.3.GA's `server` directory comes with 3 deployment sub-directories:

1. all
2. default
3. minimal

If I a copy a `.ear` of mine to the `default/deploy` sub-directory, JBoss picks it up on startup and runs it.

I now would like to place it in a sibling directory to default, i.e.:

1. all
2. default
3. minimal
4. mine

When I do that, JBoss does not even know that `mine` is there and thus does not attempt to load it.

**How I tell JBoss to look at the `mine` sibling directory for applications to load?**

I found hints in the following thread:
 https://developer.jboss.org/thread/56120 but this seems to be the solution for a different problem (i.e. *after* JBoss found that sibling directory and `jboss-service.xml` in there).

---

**Update:**  I discovered that passing the sibling directory's name as `-c` command line argument: `org.jboss.Main -c mine` changes the Server Home Dir and loads the application(s) from there.

Where can I learn more about the `-c` option? Is there a comprehensive reference of such options?

Comment: This https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters refers to version 7.1 but may provide a hint. Still looking for the right way to tell JBoss to look at a sibling directory for applications to load upon startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the sibling directory's name as the `-c` command line argument:

```
org.jboss.Main -c mine
```

changes the Server Home Dir and loads the application(s) from there.

I have not been able to find a comprehensive reference/documentation of such options. The best I could find was these:

1. https://gist.github.com/agea/8783986
2. https://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/pdf/jboss-docbook
3. http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html_single/